# How to show data from mysql using AJAX into text field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Previously I could not know about ajax. therefore I want to ask.
I want to display my wordlist from mysql into a text field but in array. this is the index.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" >
<h2>View data</h2>
<h4>Word List : </h4>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input id="wordlist" type="text" class="form-control" name="wordlist">
        </div><br>
        <button id="display" title="Generate Word">Generate</button>
        <div class="input-single">
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
     $(document).ready(function() {
    
        $("#display").click(function() {
          $.ajax({    
            type: "GET",
            url: "view_ajax.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(){
                $('').html();
            }
    
        });
    });
    });

</script>
```

And then this is the process.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = ""; 
$dbname = "posts";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$con) {
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    $sql = "select wordlist from word"; 
    
     $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
     $result = array(); 
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
     array_push($result, 
     array('wordlist'=>$row[0]));
     }
     
     echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result)); 
     mysqli_close($con);
    
    ?>
```

I will be very helpful if you can give an answer. Thank you

Comment: Your `dataType: "html"` should be `dataType: "json"` . Also , add `data` as parameter here `success: function(data){` where `data` will contain return response from your server. After changing that show output of `data` i.e : `console.log(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP loop to something like this:

```
 $result = array(); 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $result[]= $row[0];
 }
 echo json_encode(array('wordlist'=>$result));
```

Then, in your JS, see below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#display").click(function() {
    /*$.ajax({    
            type: "GET",
            url: "view_ajax.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                // use the code below in this area
            }
    
        });*/
    let response = {
      "wordlist": ["This", "is", "the", "return", "from", "your", "server"]
    } // this is what the response object will look like in your success function above

    let output

    // normal comma delimited response
    output = response.wordlist.join(",");

    // or if you want to keep the quotes
    output = JSON.stringify(response.wordlist);
    output = output.substr(1, output.length - 2);

    // use .val() to set the value of an input
    $('#wordlist').val(output);


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>View data</h2>
  <h4>Word List : </h4>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="wordlist" type="text" class="form-control" name="wordlist">
  </div><br>
  <button id="display" title="Generate Word">Generate</button>
  <div class="input-single">
  </div>
```

Comment: I feel grateful for the answer you gave.
but in your code, you declare the array. how to get the result data from from MYSQL ?

`$result = array(); 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $result[]= $row[0];
 }
 echo json_encode(array('wordlist'=>$result));`

Comment: You already have that in process.php. That is where you should update with the code I gave you (that you pasted into that last comment). That will build the array from the query `$sql = "select wordlist from word"; ` and echo so your `$ajax` will pick it up

Comment: okay i'll try it. thanks for your response